# Storing variable in function?

Tags: javascript

I made a typo in my code but it somehow still works.

```
let stuffs = [];
function stuff(thing) {
  stuff[0] = thing; // should be stuffs[0] = thing;
}
stuff("item");
```

I expected to get an error but somehow it still works.
You can even get `"item"` with `stuff[0]`. What is going on here? Should I use this?

Comment: Actually `stuff` refers to the `function` so its setting property of function. Use `console.log(stuff)` to understand better.

Comment: @MaheerAli consider making this into an answer...too late.

Comment: @ctt I have got the max rep I could today. I can't get more so don't want to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript *almost everything that has a structure* inherits from Object.

In JavaScript objects can have any property.

With this statements you can see that a `function` is an object actually, so you can set all the properties that you want to it, just like a simple `{}` (with small limitations, as functions have another set of properties that plain objects don't have).

With this snippet you can check that functions inherit from `Object`.

```js
function myFunc() {
    // empty! :-)
}

console.log("Func inherits from Object:", myFunc instanceof Object);
console.log("Array inherits from Object:", [] instanceof Object);
console.log("Object inherits from Object:", {} instanceof Object);
console.log("constant string inherits from Object:", "test" instanceof Object);
console.log(" * constant string DON'T inherits from Object but...");
console.log("String constructor inherits from Object:", String instanceof Object);
```

Comment: Setting property of primitive types also don't throw error even though the property didn't gets set.\

Comment: Didn't get set because primitive types don't inherit from Object, as you can see in the example. Don't throws an error because primitives are "property accessible", meaning that you can access `length` for strings, call functions and whatever you write next to a dot. Because they don't inherit from Object, then when you access a non-existant property then the value is not saved, because the only way to save random properties is to inherit from Object. If don't throws an error I guess that is because of specification. JavaScript is really relaxed, as you already know haha.